# Sophos SSL VPN with ssh socks proxy over google cloud

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, ssl

I was given Sophos VPN client installation file for Windows. When I try to connect to VPN using the installed client, it fails. The reason is probably due to some ip addresses are blocked in my country.
So I created an instance of google cloud compute engine and connect to it using:

```
ssh -D 1080 username@XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

Then Internet options->Connections tab->Lan settings->Advanced proxy server->Socks: 127.0.0.1 port 1080.
After that all websites think I'm now browsing from google cloud instance. If I try connecting to VPN using Sophos now, it fails again.
Is Sophos using my shh tunnel? If yes, why could it fail again?

Comment: It might not be. The settings your referring to are mostly for SOCKS-enabled Microsoft applications (and any other applications that refer to these settings for their config). SOCKS client is not a functionality provided by the operating system, the client needs to implement it.

Comment: Ok, Sophos settings do have an option to use System proxy. If I choose them, it connects, however it seems not to connect to the services available on the VPN network.

Comment: You'll probably have to disable the SOCKS proxy for all other services on your system, otherwise it'll be bypassing the VPN in favor of the SOCKS proxy.

Comment: I did disable it. Sophos is connected through my socks proxy. But the system doesn't use Sophos vpn for some reason. It just continues using my usual unprotected connection.